# ANGULAR 8 MIME TYPE ERROR : Failed to load module

Tags: angular

Getting the issue on changing baseHref in angular 8.

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I want to deploy a site to example.com/app so I changed the baseHref to "/app/" from "/". Now, I'm getting MIME type error.

**The CSS, JS and other resources load my index.html file content only.**

I tried adding:

1. type = "text/javascript" to my javascript tags removing module and nomodule attributes and all but it doesn't work.

When I give my baseHref as  "/" it works locally but I am not able to deploy it to example.com/app as it takes all resources from "example.com/" and I get 404 error.

Some reference links:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30835

I'm trying to host an angular app from NodeJS using express to statically serve it. It works when base href is "/" but not on "/app".

Comment: can you share more details

Comment: Yeah.. what you wanna know?